# how can I extract zip files, which was uploaded by user?

Tags: php, file-upload, zip, chmod, mkdir

So, I want to create a system where user uploads in a zip file the files of a 3d model and the model can be shown, stored, etc

So, I got the file, I place it into a folder, permanently, And unzip it into another temp folder, just to see if it is a 3d model.

I tried like this:

```
                  $target_dir = "upload/";
                  $targetfilename = rand().$_FILES['file']['name'];
                  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_dir.$targetfilename);

                  //unzip the file into temp folder
                  $tmp_dir = $target_dir.rand();
                  mkdir($tmp_dir);  
                  chmod($tmp_dir, 0777);
                  //chmod($targetfilename, 0777); //this not working, maybe isn't the right way

                  $zip = new ZipArchive;
                  $res = $zip->open($targetfilename);
                  if ($res === TRUE) {
                    // extract it to the path we determined above
                    $zip->extractTo($tmp_dir);
                    $zip->close();
                    echo 'SUCCESS';
                  } else {
                    echo 'ERROR';
                  }
```

I do not get any errors, but the zip can't be unzipped. Any idea? How can I resolve this?

Comment: `$target_dir.rand()` < I am pretty sure that that is the reason why it's not extracting to a randomly named folder that doesn't yet exist. You're trying to upload it before it exists. You need to create another variable for it, using it for the created folder. Enable error reporting.

Comment: I have enabled all errors with `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` But I didn't get any error for this, only if I want to set the permissions fot `$targetfilename`

Comment: and I tried to rewrite the section what you are talking about @FunkFortyNiner , but doesn't make any changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't `$targetfilename` is in `$target_dir` folder?

If so, changing
`$res = $zip->open($targetfilename);` to

`$res = $zip->open($target_dir.$targetfilename);` might solve your problem.